# Processing and matching large amounts of data

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have one large database table of request data, much like Apache request logs, of about 50 million rows:

```
request_url
user_agent
created
```

that contains data like this:

```
/profile/Billy
Mozilla.....
2012-06-17...

/profile/Jane
Mozilla.....
2012-06-17...
```

I then have my user database table, with all my user data including usernames.

At the moment, every night, I process the request data for the previous day, row by row and see if it contains an URL that matches one of the usernames in the users table. If it does, I increment a total in another table that stores stats that allows users to see how many pageviews they got for any particular day.

However as the datasets grow, this is becoming resource intensive and can also take a long time to complete, even when grouping the request data by URL and grabbing a count for that group.

Is there a better way of processing this information to get the end result I need? The request data is going to be logged anyway, so it would be preferable to to generate the stats after the fact rather than incrementing the total on every page view.

I'm running this on one server, so distributed processing of the data on multiple servers isn't required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with a fresh log-table every day. When the day is done, use it to increment the totals, then append it to that huge main log-table and delete it.

Answer (score 1):

Incrementing total on every page view is your best option. It saves trouble of "search" later on for each user separately. It's just one extra query of update on every pageview, and thus processing load is spread out throughout the day instead of single time (Plus your stats stay updated all the time, instead of being updated daily)

If you are insistent on doing in SQL, you might consider

```
SELECT COUNT(request_url) FROM your_table WHERE request_url LIKE %/profile/username%
```

(though I am not sure if that's what you're already doing?)

Comment: Yes that is fairly close to what I'm doing. I have simplified my example somewhat, as I do look for things like /profile/username/photos and count those as pageviews as well.

Answer (score 0):

Start looking into analytic database like Infobright.  Column Based storeage engines are huge in the big data initiatives and are built for doing in memory analytics on aggregates as well as ad hoc querying.

*Disclaimer: the author is affiliated with Infobright.*